# Unable to fire a Laravel Event from within a Laravel Redis PUB/SUB Subscriber. [Only happens when I'm interacting with queues]

Tags: php, laravel, redis, predis

This only seems to be happening when I am using queues.

I have a Node publisher and a Laravel subscriber. The Node publisher sends a message and the Laravel subscriber receives it.

When I receive this message, I would like to dispatch a job. If i'm interacting with queues I receive this error.

"[Predis\Response\ServerException] ERR only (P)SUBSCRIBE / (P)UNSUBSCRIBE / QUIT allowed in this context"

Is there something I'm missing here? It seems like I'm most of the way there. The only thing I can think of is that the Laravel subscriber has to use a different connection from defaut, which is the same connection the queue uses.

Any help is mucho appreciated.

Comment: It's like you said, you need to setup a second redis connection (in config/database.php)